# Xero API - Payments

Tags: paypal, xero-api

I am trying to integrate the Xero API into an application I am working on. I have the ability to get the invoices as well as set up new payment.

I want to make it so that customers can come online and pay their invoice using Go Cardless and then mark the invoice as paid once the payment has gone through.

Can I do this using the API or will I need to integrate the Go Cardless API in order to do this and then once it's successful it then marks the payment as complete?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Go Cardless.
But once the invoice is paid through your app, you need to make sure that you write back information to Xero to make that invoice status change to Paid.
You can do it through Invoices and Paymnets  Endpoint.
You need to add Payments against that Invoice ID. once the invoice is fully paid, status of that will change to PAID.

> Apply payments to approved AR and AP invoices

More information on request object for Payments Endpoint:
[Payments](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payments/#PUT)

More Documentation for [Invoices](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices/)